# How to replace wood plank flooring?

Tags: flooring, floor, replacement, vinyl-flooring

I have plank wood flooring (not real wood, the snap together type). There is a piece that needs replaced and the problem is that it's not an edge piece.

Is there a way to replace it without having to take out all other pieces leading up to it?

Comment: It depends on the specific brand or type. Please revise to provide more information.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure the brand, the floor was installed before I bought the house. Also- when you say "type", what information are you asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot like replacing a piece of tongue and groove hardwood flooring.  Here's what I would do.

Cut the piece of flooring to be replaced lengthwise, taking care not to damage the 4 adjoining pieces or the subfloor.  A circular saw set to the right dept could do most of the work.  Then use an oscillating saw or hand saw to finish up the cut. It doesn't have to be pretty, since your throwing this piece away.

Remove the two halves of the wood plank, prying up from the center.  If you do this right, you should be left with the two adjacent pieces of plank, one with a tongue and the other with a groove.

Cut your replacement piece to the proper length.  Then cut the bottom of the groove on the long side off.

Carefully insert the tongue of the new piece into the groove of the existing plank, holding the new piece at a slight angle.  After the tongue is fully inserted, pivot the new plank down so that the top of the groove lays on top of the tongue of the adjoining piece.  You may want to put a bit of adhesive between the top of the groove in the new piece and tongue of the existing piece in order to hold that edge down.

I was going to sketch something up.  But there are numerous references on line with graphics and videos that are better than what I would create.

Comment: This should work fine for tongue & groove flooring, however the OP specifically said her floor is "the snap together type", which indicates (to me) that it's "click-lock". Does this still work in that situation? (No idea, I've never messed with any of the new floating floors.)

Comment: @FreeMan - Yes click lock vinyl flooring can be replaced as described by SteveSh. However since click lock vinyl flooring has tongue and grooves on the ends as well as the sides it would be necessary to also cut off the bottom side on one end of the flooring tile/plank. Every brand and product type can be somewhat different so careful evaluation should be made by studying the replacement tile/plank before doing any cutting at all.

Comment: @Michael Karas - Thanks for pointing that out.  I was trying to come up with an 80% or 90% solution, recognizing that no matter how complete I thought my answer was, there was always going to be another case/floor type that I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is close to the centre also.

The best way is to remove the other pieces, but is possible to carefully cut that piece out.

Flooring might need gluing down at that piece.

Measuring for the cuts is very important to do right.

Comment: This is extremely vague and not particularly helpful.